# Train/test split on time-based data with lagged features

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, data-leakage, train-test-split

I am working with data on bank transactions, and am using RFM (recency/frequency/monetary value) features like days since last transaction, number of transactions last n days, average value of transactions last n days.

I am planning on splitting the data based on time. Let's say I have a year's worth of data, and I'm holding out the last three months for my test set.

Should I compute the RFM features before or after the train/test split? My hunch is that it should be **after** to prevent data leakage, but that means that I'll essentially have to completely exclude data that is n days. In other words, if my window is 30 days, in order to have accurate RFM data in the test set, I would need to discard the first month from the test set. Is that right?

The model once deployed would likely be updated weekly with the full range of data available.

Comment: Consider using rolling windows (something that is fairly standard in time series analysis and forecasting), perhaps it will be more intuitive.

Comment: Yup, am using rolling windows.

Comment: Then you are not really holding out a 3-month test set, because all the data except for the last $h$ observations is part of training data (for one window or another) if you are predicting $h$ steps ahead. As the window rolls, the test set gradually becomes the training set. But that does not imply data leakage in a sense that would be undesirable. (This comment is more about terminology and phrasing than substance.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no data leakage if you construct the test samples' features using past data. The test data doesn't leak into the training, so it's not a data leakage.